# Closed range assumption in definition of Fredholm operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

There are two definitions of Fredholm operators (on a Hilbert space) that are commonly used. The first is that $\dim\ker T<\infty$ and $\dim\,\mathrm{coker} T<\infty$. An argument using the open mapping theorem then shows that the range of $T$ is closed. The other definition is that $\dim\ker T<\infty$, $\dim\ker T^{*}<\infty$ and the range of $T$ is closed.

I am trying to find an example where $T\in B(H)$ satisfies $\dim\ker T<\infty$ and $\dim\ker T^{*}<\infty$ but does not have closed range.

I considered the following: $H=\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N})$ and $T$ is defined on basis elements $e_{n}$ by $Te_{n}=\frac{1}{n}e_{n}$. It seems to me that $T$ is injective, self-adjoint, and its range is not closed because the sequence $T(1,0,0,0,\ldots), T(1,1,0,0,\ldots), T(1,1,1,0,\ldots)$ converges in $H$ to $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots)$, which is not in the range of $T$.

I hope someone can check the example, or perhaps give a simpler example (or a correct one in the event that mine is wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is correct. You definitely have $T^{\star}=T$. If your $T$ were surjective, then the inverse of $T$ would have to be continuous because $T$ is continous, which means that the graph of $T$ is closed in $X\times X$ and implies that the graph of $T^{-1}$ is also closed. However, $\|Tx\| \ge C\|x\|$ cannot hold for all $x \in X$ for any fixed constant $C > 0$ because $\|Te_{n}\|=\frac{1}{n}\|e_{n}\|$. The range of $T$ is dense and, therefore, the range of $T$ is not closed.